# Minify vendor.js file in Laravel Mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to optimize the page load and after doing a lighthouse review i found out that vendor.js file is 5MB and doesn't use dead code elimination, although, I'm using dynamic imports, so vendor.js file should be smaller, obviously I'm doing something wrong.

I'm dynamically importing components like below:

```
const app = new Vue({
    vuetify,
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'currency-converter': () => import(
          /* webpackChunkName: "components/js/Assets/Menu/Currency" */ 
          './components/Assets/Menu/Currency.vue'
        ),
...
```

When loading the page i can see that each component gets loaded when inspecting the network tab, the vendo.js file also gets loaded and it's 5MB where that shouldn't be the case when i dynamically import each component, so i should eliminate the dead code which is not getting used somehow.

My mix.js file:

```
mix.js('resources/js/admin.js', 'public/js').js('public/assets/admin/main.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue().vuetify('vuetify-loader')
    .sass('resources/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css')
    .css('public/assets/css/main.css', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
        output: {
            publicPath: '/',
            chunkFilename: '[name].js?id=[contenthash]',
         },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\]locale$/, /en-gb|el/),
            new NodePolyfillPlugin()
        ],
    });

    mix.extract();

    if (mix.inProduction()) {
        mix.version();
    }
```

I looked for resources but I haven't found out how to do this properly.

Comment: Looks like optimizations are only enabled for `inProduction`, perhaps that's the reason, see https://github1s.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/blob/HEAD/src/builder/webpack-default.js#L45-L53

Comment: Optimization does happen, it minifies the files in production, although i want to use dead code elimination, vendor.js file must be way below 4MB since I'm dynamically import way less components in each page.

Comment: If you could provide a repo I could play with it, can't really suggest much for now

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the dynamically imported components are also present in the vendor.js?
In my experience vendor bundles can get this large - if you do not configure the server correctly to compress the sources for transport (gzip, brotli).
Perhaps this is just a config issue on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use tree shaking plugin to remove the dead code, this is really your only option outside of using production mode for optimisations in Mix.

```
const DeadCodePlugin = require('webpack-deadcode-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new DeadCodePlugin({
      patterns: ['**/*.(js|jsx|css)'],
      exclude: ['**/*.(stories|spec).(js|jsx)'],
    }),
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Also have you considered using the minify plugin for webpack?

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  // ...
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin(),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin(),
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.MinimizePlugin(),
  ],
  // ...
};
```